# How to display infomation based on APP_USER Id ? oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a table call **employee** which has the **employee_name** and **status** field. The status field has **'admin'** and **'staff'**.

When I log in as app user (once I am an admin), I want to be able to see all employees whether admin or staff. However when I log in as app user (and I am in the staff category), I just want to see my own info.

I am using

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
 WHERE UPPER(employee_name) = UPPER(:APP_USER) 
    OR status = 'staff'
```

but it is not giving me the desired result. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to create a function which shows whether `APP_USER` is (or is not) an admin. Then use it in a `SELECT` statement.

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table employee
  2    (employee_name varchar2(20),
  3     status        varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into employee
  2    select 'LITTLE', 'staff' from dual union all
  3    select 'FOOT'  , 'admin' from dual union all
  4    select 'RAWLE' , 'staff' from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> create or replace function f_admin_01 (par_app_user in varchar2)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    -- RETURN 1 if par_app_user is 'admin'
  5    --        0 if it is not
  6    retval number;
  7  begin
  8    select case when status = 'admin' then 1
  9                else 0
 10           end
 11      into retval
 12      from employee
 13      where employee_name = par_app_user;
 14
 15    return retval;
 16  end;
 17  /

Function created.
```

Testing (note that - in Apex - you obviously don't have to declare a variable nor assign a value to it. Also, `:APP_USER` is always uppercase, so there's no point in applying `UPPER` function to it):

```
SQL> var app_user varchar2(20)
SQL> exec :app_user := 'LITTLE'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select *
  2  from employee
  3  where employee_name = case when f_admin_01(:APP_USER) = 1 then employee_name
  4                             else :APP_USER
  5                        end;

EMPLOYEE_NAME        STATUS
-------------------- --------------------
LITTLE               staff

SQL> exec :app_user := 'FOOT'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select *
  2  from employee
  3  where employee_name = case when f_admin_01(:APP_USER) = 1 then employee_name
  4                             else :APP_USER
  5                        end;

EMPLOYEE_NAME        STATUS
-------------------- --------------------
LITTLE               staff
FOOT                 admin
RAWLE                staff

SQL>
```

Comment: hi @littlefoot just a minor issue now the info above works when I create a employee1 table with  employee_name and status... But my original employee table has more fields EMPLOYEE_INFO_ID,
       EMPLOYEE_NAME,
       CONTRACT_START_PERIOD,
       CONTRACT_END_PERIOD,
       POSITION,
       COMPLETED,STATUS  and for some reason when I use the above info with the original table its not working which I don't understand.. Can u help ?

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work"? Any error? If so, which one? If possible, edit your original message (question) and copy/paste your SQL*Plus session so that I/we could see what you did and how Oracle responded.

Comment: no there is no error it just doesn't show any results 
I have a table call employee which has the  EMPLOYEE_INFO_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, CONTRACT_START_PERIOD, CONTRACT_END_PERIOD, POSITION, COMPLETED,STATUS. The status field has 'admin' and 'staff'. 
When I log in as app user (once I am an admin), I want to be able to see all employees whether admin or staff. However when I log in as app user (and I am in the staff category), I just want to see my own info.

Comment: but as I said if I create an employee1 table with just employee_name and status it works.. so I am a little baffle because there is no info change in the table

Comment: Huh, no idea ... as you can see, code I posted works. I don't know why it doesn't work in your case. Once again: copy/paste your session. I can't debug code I can't see.

Comment: yea no doubt your code works. tested it with the dummy table and all went as plan thanks again for that. in terms of the session am not getting any errors am using the sql developer.. and all commands was successful so that's why am a little confuse. so I don't know what what to send cause there is nothing to debug.. but if u want me send it still I can

Comment: Are usernames in your new table ("employee") stored in upper case? :APP_USER is in upper case, so - maybe that's the culprit?

Comment: littefoot you are a boss.. that was the issue.. thanks again you have been such a big help... am looking forward for more advice from you in the future

Comment: No problem. As of the code, in function, line 13, apply the UPPER function: `where upper(employee_name) = upper(par_app_user)` so that case wouldn't matter.